# Protractor test script is not getting object data from function

Tags: protractor, 2-way-object-databinding

Need help on getting object data that populated in a function to test script, please. Here are the details:

```js
candidate Data = function() {
    "firstName": "firstname",
    "lastName": "lastname", 
    "mobilePhone": "phone",
    "primaryEmail": "email"
};
module.exports = new candidateData();
```

```js
test script is as As below:
var testData = require('candidateData');
var myFunction = require('getData');

testCandiate = {};
testCandidate = testData;

it('Get Candidate Data', function(){
    myFunction.getCandidateData(testCandidate);
    console.log(`FirstName is -: ${testCandidate.firstName}:-`);
    console.log(`LastName is -: ${testCandidate.firstName}:-`);
    console.log(`Phone is: ${testCandidate.mobilePhone}:-`);
    console.log(`Primary Email is -: ${testCandidate.primaryEmail}:-`);
});
```

the function is defined in separate js file as:
// As I am capturing data from edit fields of a page, so using get Attribute value to get value

```js
var getData = function() {
    this.getCandidateData = function(testObj){  
        page.firstname.getAttribute("value").then(function(fname){
            testObj.firstName = fname;
        }); 
        page.lastname.getAttribute("value").then(function(lname){
            testObj.lastName = lname;
        });
        page.phone.getAttribute("value").then(function(phone){
            testObj.mobilePhone = phone;
        });
        page.email.getAttribute("value").then(function(email){
            testObj.primaryEmail = email;
        });
    };
};
module.exports = new getData();
```

After Running Script I am getting console log results AS below instead of Populated data on the fields:

First Name is -: firstName :- 
Last Name is -: lastName :- 
Mobile Phone is -: mobilePhone :-
Primary Email is -: primaryEmail :-

please need help.

Comment: First thing: are the syntax error accidental or this is an exact copy of your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a protractor issue but a basic misunderstanding you have of promises, as you are running into a race condition. You call myfunction.getCandidateData() which calls 4 separate functions that return promises. While those functions are getting the attributes you wanted *javascript continues on in your code*. This means that the console.log statements *fire immediately without waiting for the four getAttribute promises to resolve*.

To fix this you will have to convert getCandidateData into a function that returns a promise. As a proof of concept try this to see that firstName will be populated:

```js
var testData = require('candidateData');
var myFunction = require('getData');

testCandiate = {};
testCandidate = testData;

it('Get Candidate Data', function(){
    myFunction.getCandidateData(testCandidate).then(() => {
        console.log(`FirstName is -: ${testCandidate.firstName}:-`);
    });
    // console.log(`LastName is -: ${testCandidate.firstName}:-`);
    // console.log(`Phone is: ${testCandidate.mobilePhone}:-`);
    // console.log(`Primary Email is -: ${testCandidate.primaryEmail}:-`);
});
```

And

```js
var getData = function() {
  this.getCandidateData = function(testObj){  
      return page.firstname.getAttribute("value").then(function(fname){
          testObj.firstName = fname;
      }); 
      /*
      page.lastname.getAttribute("value").then(function(lname){
          testObj.lastName = lname;
      });
      page.phone.getAttribute("value").then(function(phone){
          testObj.mobilePhone = phone;
      });
      page.email.getAttribute("value").then(function(email){
          testObj.primaryEmail = email;
      });
      */
  };
};
module.exports = new getData();
```

Comment: Thank you Keeleon! lemme try it.